# My Sql query return an empty array with req.params.id in nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I have i Mysql query with nodejs like this :

```
  application.get('/Modification/:idt',function(req,res){


        connection.query("SELECT * FROM memos WHERE idMemo = 'req.params.idt'",function (error, rows){
         if (error) {
        console.log("error ocurred",error);
        }
        else {
            console.log(req.params.idt);
            console.log(rows);
            var no = rows;
            res.render('memosModif.ejs', {no});
        } 

    });

    });
```

and my query return an empty array even if req.params.idt return an int value like 1 or 2 ... , but when i replace req.params.id with a int like 1 or 2 ... the query returns the right result 
i dont understand why and how to fix that .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing the `idMemo` column to the **string literal** `'req.params.idt'`. Instead, you should bind the value from this variable:

```
connection.query("SELECT * FROM memos WHERE idMemo = ?", req.params.idt, function (error, rows) {
```

Comment: i changed it with your query and it works fine , i lost hours trying to fix the problem , Thank you !

Comment: Mkh_RMD, if this solved your problem, please consider marking it as the accepted answer to give @Mureinik credit and let others know you've found a solution. Welcome, and good luck! https://stackoverflow.com/tour